# Webglogic when does it change server Health

Tags: weblogic

so on the left hand side of weblogic console panel...there are 5 different health status of the servers. I see weblogic change them status to warning whenever there is a stuck thread. However, when one does in wlst script.

connection(name,pass,url)
serverRuntime()
get('HealthState') the server health returns Health_Ok even though on the panel on the left hand  side the health status is warning.

Any tips are appreciated

I tried serverLifeCycleRuntimes() by the way. I googled every website regarding Weblogic and not being able to figure out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well I kinda figure it out. It has subsystems. What I do is I cd into JDBC, check the health, then cd into ThreadPool check the health. When the server changes to overload? I do not know

Comment: someone Kudo me please